# Running an ASP.NET 1.1 application under 2.0

Tags: asp.net, migration

I have an application written in ASP.NET 1.1. If I switch IIS to use 2.0 what issues am I likely to see? Initial tests have thrown no problems, but I was wondering if anyone had experience of running ASP.NET 1.1 applications under 2.0 and could maybe point out some areas to watch out for?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure that you are not running different web applications in the same application pool if they require different versions of the .NET framework.

Create separate app pools (at least one for each version of the framework).

Maybe also have a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2005/11/14/breaking-changes-between-net-framework-1-1-and-2-0.aspx) by Brad Abrams about breaking changes between .NET framework 1.1 and 2.0. Here's a short quote :

> ...we work *very* hard to ensure that
>   your V1.1 apps will this just work on
>   2.0, but none-the-less, this doc is likely worth a quick scan as you
>   migrate to 2.0

Answer (score 0):

When we migrated our 1.1 applications to 2.0, I don't think we had any problems.  There were a handful of cases where the compiler warned us that we should use a different (updated) assembly, but other than that everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most ASP.NET 1.1 applications will run just fine under ASP.NET 2.0. One thing to watch though is that you don't run an ASP.NET 1.1 and an ASP.NET 2.0 application in the same application pool.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem we had was connected with the insertion of the xhtmlConformance element in the web.config file connected with javascript libraries, removing it worked fine for us
[check this post from Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/10/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Usually asp.net 1.1 application migration to 2.0 does not raise any issues. You might need to change the location where you put the class files.

You will see some warnings, some deprecated method call etc.